# How do I add the same property in all levels of a tree-like type definition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need a type generic to do self reference. And the next deep level know what the type is.
Even with an error in the typescript, `const v` knows how to identify each property.
Importantly, it is necessary to have N levels. Perhaps it would be simpler than I am thinking?

```
type RemoveArray<R> = R extends (infer U)[] ? U : R;

type Base<R> = RemoveArray<R> & {
  blabla: string
  data?: Base<RemoveArray<R['data']>>[]
}
type BaseArray<R> = Base<R>[]

//------

type Level2 = {
  d: string
  e: number
  //f:Level3[]
}

type Level1 = {
  a: string
  b: string
  data: Level2[]
}

const v: BaseArray<Level1> = [{
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  blabla: 'lalala',
  data: [
    { blabla: 'lala', d: 'd', e: 'e' }
  ]
}]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2B7AbhAggJwwQxAHhgD4oBeWKCAD2AgDsATAZygAoBLWgMwgygFUAlAG0AulAD8-KAC5YAbgBQC0JCgAhbIwgFiZOElSYc%20IlABkUAN4KoUAEYAbbI%20yzGwDBwDmNqPWzA2OKyGloECCjoWLgEQgDk-oFxIoSEogoAvsrg0KFRxjqk6praROkKAPQVALS1dUoq0AAyEKgOAExF1rb0bh7evhCytACu8HY8vlWc0i1tAMzpWdmqcxAOAIxdvq5Q7p60PrZ2fQdHfgG7ax1LSgDGiLTuUMghJUYx1xu6UELdULs4tg4gAaXwnKBxOyg8FOFyyOJOJHAsE9S6yIS%20WyWexwpwI5GgvwI%20hEoaQiBxKBZWwiTIiIA)

Answer (score 1):

Your question could gain from clarification, so I am assuming some things from the code you've provided:

1. All `Level`s have the property `data: T[]` if they are to include children;
2. You have lots of types which all have the `data` property holding its children;
3. The question "How do I add the same property in all levels of a tree-like type definition in TypeScript?"

So, to answer that, I suggest you use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to infer when you need to declare the `data` property.

```js
type ExtractDataType<T> = T extends { data: Array<infer DataType> }
  ? DataType
  : never;

type AddBlaBla<T, DataType = ExtractDataType<T>> = T & {
  blabla: string;
  data?: AddBlaBla<DataType>[];
};
```

This type definition allow me to make this 3-level deep type definition gain the `blabla` keyword:

```js
interface Level2 {
  d: string;
  e: number;
  data: Level3[];
}

interface Level1 {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  data: Level2[];
}

interface Level3 {
  f: string;
  g: string;
}

const v: AddBlaBla<Level1>[] = [
  {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    blabla: "lalala",
    data: [
      {
        blabla: "s",
        d: "d",
        e: 2,
        data: [
          {
            blabla: 'blabla',
            f: "oi",
            g: "tchau",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2B7AbhAggJwwQxAHhgD4oBeWKCAD2AgDsATAZygAoBLWgMwgygFUAlAG0AulAD8-KAC5YAbgBQoSFACi1HAGNgAEWzBsAFXAQ8h4mUMVqdJlADeUevuyzMOfB2689B45GIAXwUoCShfIxMQmShaCFQMRSUTKDR6egAhABtsbOwzABpwl39oMnVgLV0SkzNCCygrADIHaIAjHI7XKEZKjgBzRVDnA3E3dLy8vAjSwlFFQKSAeiWAWnWNhQUOGgxObE1oABl4iCyAJlbh2V6MAaGKWVoAV3g2ngeR7pPULIBmeYKYLbWi7faHKA-M4ARiuUG6t3u7RufVog2iX1kUIugOBOx44OOp3%20cM4KLuaIe-XJSOBmkQtF6UGQ40yOSm2OhczEZCE0Xs0VC3QARNhhQVBVA2rJhW1xZKul0ZTkVWKJaFhi5ZHyNRqBbrdYqcjLGPKDRr6DL6GbzY8oOd1bbMVAdbbQvq3Rqjd0AOTen2Oz1QMlQYWINg2oPU0PATQAC2wz0jtsCgYNIjToVTkoz0WzIkUQA)

Also, may I suggest you rewrite the question title to make it easier for future reference?